# SQL Query to truncate table in IBM DB2

Tags: syntax, db2, truncate

Can any one give me the syntax to truncate a table in IBM DB2.

I m running the following command: `truncate table tableName immediate;`

The eror is DB2

> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=table;truncate ;JOIN , DRIVER=3.50.152
>    Message: An unexpected token "table" was found following "truncate ".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN ".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152

The syntax matches the one specified in the reference docs of IBM : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_sql_truncate.htm

Comment: What version of DB2 are you running?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a great article about [truncating](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#bulk-truncate_table-db2), here is the Gist of DB2 stuff

Almost follows the standard.(since version 9.7) 
DB2 requires that the IMMEDIATE keyword be added the the ordinary TRUNCATE TABLE statement, e.g.:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE someschema.sometable IMMEDIATE
```

TRUNCATE TABLE must be the first statement in a transaction. A transaction starting with TRUNCATE TABLE may include other statements, but if the transaction is rolled back, the TRUNCATE TABLE operation is not undone. 
DB2s TRUNCATE TABLE operation has a number of optional arguments, see the documentation for more on this; especially, the REUSE STORAGE argument may be important for ad-hoc DBA tasks.
In DB2 versions < 9.7, you may abuse the IMPORT statement. Unfortunately, you need to know which operating system the command is executed from for this to work:

On unix-like systems: 
IMPORT FROM /dev/null OF DEL REPLACE INTO tablename
On Windows: 
IMPORT FROM NUL OF DEL REPLACE INTO tablename
IMPORT cannot be abused in all contexts. E.g., when working with dynamic SQL (from Java/.NET/PHP/...—not using the db2 command line processor), you need to wrap the IMPORT command in a call to ADMIN_CMD, e.g.:

```
CALL ADMIN_CMD('IMPORT FROM /dev/null OF DEL REPLACE INTO tablename')
```

IMPORT seems to be allowed in a transaction involving other operations, however it implies an immediate COMMIT operation.

The ALTER TABLE command may also be abused to quickly empty a table, but it requires more privileges, and may cause trouble with rollforward recovery.

This was taken from the website:
http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#bulk-truncate_table-db2

Comment: Thx. IMPORT FROM /dev/null OF DEL REPLACE INTO tablename did the trick

Answer (score 3):

If you are using DB2 for AS400, IMMEDIATE TRUNCATE TABLE will NOT work.  The equivallent work around is to either:

DELETE FROM [tableName]

then if it is an auto increment equivalant column, run:

ALTER TABLE  ALTER COLUMN  RESTART WITH 1

OR the faster (most efficient way)

Pass a command to the system to clear out the Physical File

Java syntax:

```
CommandCall command = new CommandCall(new AS400(AS400SystemName, AS400JavaUser, AS400JavaPwd));
try {
    command.run("CLRPFM FILE(as400SchemaName/" + tableName + ")");
```

Comment: As it turns out, there is a way to actually do the equivalent of TRUNCATE TABLE, not just deleting all the rows. The command syntax is not at all intuitive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3616556/95852

Comment: IBM finally decided to add the TRUNCATE statement to Db2 for i, as of version [7.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafztruncate.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of DB2 are you using? The `truncate table` command was introduced in DB2 v9 (at least on the mainframe, which appears to be what you're asking about based on the link).

You may have to resort to the `delete from` option although [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0402greenstein/) gives a stored procedure way of doing it in DB2 v8.

Answer (score 0):

use **truncate 'table_name' immediate**

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reference documentation available for TRUNCATE in DB2 from 9.7 version

[DB2 Reference for TRUNCATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053474.html)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 on z/OS V10 
Empty one of your tables: truncate table; followed by commit work. Ex. truncate temp; 
Someone else table: truncate owner.table  Ex: truncate student.work ;
I have not tried this on a linked DB2. I do not know if  truncate  node2.student.work; is good.

SQL for creating list of tables automatically. Substring (substr) used because column width for table                name and creator are sooo long. Your values may be different.

```
select 'truncate table '||substr(creator,1,9)||'.'||substr(name,1,20)  
    from sysibm.systables
        where creator = 'Student';
```

Answer (score 0):

in Java make sure it's the first statement in the transaction