# How to efficiently remove all rows from a table in DB2

Tags: sql, performance, db2

I have a table that has something like half a million rows and I'd like to remove all rows.

If I do simple `delete from tbl`, the transaction log fills up. I don't care about transactions this case, I do not want to rollback in any case. I could delete rows in many transactions, but are there any better ways to this?

How to efficiently remove all rows from a table in DB2? Can I disable the transactions for this command somehow or is there special commands to do this (like [truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) in MySQL)?

After I have deleted the rows, I will repopulate the database with similar amount of new data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that following command [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006999/sql-query-to-truncate-table-in-ibm-db2) in newer versions of DB2.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE someschema.sometable IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: Bear in mind that trancate can be used only on tables that are not referenced by foreign keys. The linked article shows an alternative way to empty even those tables by loading the dev null into them CALL ADMIN_CMD('LOAD FROM /dev/null of del REPLACE INTO someschema.sometable NONRECOVERABLE'). nonrecoverable is used to avoid setting the table into backup pending

Answer (score 8):

To truncate a table in DB2, simply write:

```
alter table schema.table_name activate not logged initially with empty table
```

From what I was able to read, this will delete the table content without doing any kind of logging which will go much easier on your server's I/O.

Comment: This may not work in replicated/hadr environment because of lack of logging.

Comment: This is a very useful answer for those who need to clear a table on versions of DB2 that do not have a TRUNCATE TABLE statement.