# DB2: Purge large number of records from table

Tags: database, performance, db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 9.7 FP5 for LUW. I have a table with 2.5 million rows and I want to delete about 1 million rows and this delete operation is distributed across table. I am deleting data with 5 delete statements.

```
delete from tablename where tableky between range1 and range2
delete from tablename where tableky between range3 and range4
delete from tablename where tableky between range5 and range5
delete from tablename where tableky between range7 and range8
delete from tablename where tableky between range9 and range10
```

While doing this, first 3 deletes works properly but the 4th fails and DB2 hangs, doing nothing. Below is the process I followed, please help me on this:

```
1. Set following profile registry parameters: DB2_SKIPINSERTED,DB2_USE_ALTERNATE_PAGE_CLEANING,DB2_EVALUNCOMMITTED,DB2_SKIPDELETED,DB2_PARALLEL_IO

2.Alter bufferpools for automatic storage.

3. Turn off logging for tables (alter table tabname activate not logged initially) and delete records

4. Execute the script with +c to make sure logging is off
```

What are the best practices to delete such large amount of data? Why its failing when it is deleting data from same table and of same nature?

Comment: I have shared my experience over my blog. Please refer to this [link](http://saurabhska.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/database-shrinking-purge-a-large-amount-of-data-from-database/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is allways tricky task. The size of transaction (e.g. for safe rollback) is limited by the size of transaction log. The transaction log is filled not only by yours sql commands but also by the commands of other users using db in the same moment.

I would suggest using one of/or combination of following methods

### 1. Commits

Do commmits often - in your case I would put one commit after each delete command

### 2. Increase the size of transaction log

As I recall default db2 transaction log is not very big. The size of transaction log should be calculated/tuned for each db individually. Reference [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.spatial.doc/cfgtranslog.html) and with more details [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301kline/0301kline.html)

### 3. Stored procedure

Write and call stored procedure which does deletes in blocks, e.g.:

> ```
> -- USAGE - create: db2 -td@ -vf del_blocks.sql
> -- USAGE - call: db2 "call DEL_BLOCKS(4, ?)"
>
> drop PROCEDURE DEL_BLOCKS@
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE DEL_BLOCKS(IN PK_FROM INTEGER, IN PK_TO INTEGER)
> LANGUAGE SQL
> BEGIN
>     declare v_CNT_BLOCK     bigint;
>
>     set v_CNT_BLOCK   = 0;
>
>     FOR r_cur as c_cur cursor with hold for
>         select tableky from tablename 
>         where tableky between pk_from and pk_to
>         for read only
>     DO
>             delete from tablename where tableky=r_cur.tableky;
>
>             set v_CNT_BLOCK=v_CNT_BLOCK+1;
>
>             if v_CNT_BLOCK >= 5000 then
>                 set v_CNT_BLOCK = 0;
>                 commit;
>             end if;
>     END FOR;
>
>     commit;
> END@
> ```

### 4. Export + import with replace option

In some cases when I needed to purge very big tables or leave just small amount of records (and had no FK constraints), then I used export + import(replace). The replace import option **is very destructive - it purges the whole table before import of new records starts** (reference [of db2 import command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html)), so be sure what you're doing and make backup before. For such sensitive operations I create 3 scripts and run each separately: backup, export, import. Here is the script for export:

```
echo '===================== export started '; 
values current time;

export to tablename.del of del  
select *  from tablename where (tableky between 1 and 1000 
    or tableky between 2000 and 3000 
    or tableky between 5000 and 7000 
    ) ; 
echo '===================== export finished ';  
values current time;
```

Here is the import script:

```
echo '===================== import started ';  
values current time;

import from tablename.del of del  allow write access commitcount 2000
-- !!!! this is IMPORTANT and VERY VERY destructive option  
replace  
into tablename ;

echo '===================== import finished ';
```

### 5. Truncate command

Db2 in version 9.7 introduced TRUNCATE statement which:

> **deletes all of the rows from a table.**

Basically:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename> IMMEDIATE
```

I had no experience with TRUNCATE in db2 but in some other engines, the command is very fast and does not use transaction log (at least not in usual manner). Please check all details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006999/sql-query-to-truncate-table-in-ibm-db2) or in [official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053474.html). As solution 4, this method too **is very destructive - it purges the whole table** so be very careful before issuing the command. Ensure previous state with table/db backup doing first.

### Note about when to do this

When there are no other users on db, or ensure this by locking the table.

### Note about rollback

In transaction db (like db2) rollback can restore db state to the state when transaction started. In methods 1,3 and 4 this can't be achieved, so **if you need feature "restoring to the original state", the only option which ensures this is the method nr. 2 - increase transaction log**.

Comment: Great comment! For method 4 I had to remove `allow write access` to make it work, it turns out to be incompatible with with `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from ordpos where orderid in ((select orderid from ordpos where orderid not in (select id from ordhdr) fetch first 40000 rows only));
```

Hoping this will resolve your query :)

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that DB2 is "hanging" – more likely it's in the process of doing a Rollback after the `DELETE` operation filled the transaction log.

Make sure that you are committing after each individual `DELETE` statement.  If you are executing the script using the `+c` option for the DB2 CLP, then make sure you include an explicit `COMMIT` statement between each `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to delete the data which has millions of rows is to use commit in between the deletes. In your case you can use commit after every delete statement.

What commit does is it will clear the transction logs and make space available for other delte operations to perform.

Alternatively instad of 5 delete statements use loop and pass the delete statement to delete, After one iteration of the loop execute one commit then database will never hang and simultaneously your data will get deleted.

use some thing like this.

```
while(count<no of records)
delete from (select * from table fetch fist 50000 records only)
commit;
count= total records- no of records.
```

Answer (score 0):

If SELECT WHERE FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY can pull-in a few chunk of records,in chunks of 10 for example, then you can feed this as input into another script that will then delete these records. Rinse and repeat...

Answer (score -3):

For the benefit of everyone, [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1501data-purge-db2/index.html) is the link to my developerWorks article on the same problem. I tried different things and the one I shared on this article worked perfectly for me.