# Errror executing dynamic delete query with Prepare statement inside a DB2 Stored Procedure in IBM DB2 LUW

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, commit, db2-luw

I am trying to Delete records from a tables with huge volume of records.

Now the error is

> 'Cursor C1 identifies a prepared statement that is not a SELECT or
>   VALUES'

1-Added COMMIT,Without using COMMIT the 'Transaction Logs' are getting Full. 
 2-Added WITH HOLD statement for Cursor to remain active.

Lines with '--NEW ADDED' shows the new added code to a already working delete without COMMIT and WITH HOLD

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
TABLE1.MYPROC1 ( IN A VARCHAR(100),IN B INTEGER,IN C INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE int;
DECLARE V_CREATE_QUERY VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR V_DELETE_STATEMENT;--NEW ADDED

SET V_CREATE_QUERY='DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM '||a||' WHERE KEY         
=='||RTRIM(CHAR(B)||' ' FETCH FIRST ' || RTRIM (CHAR(C)||' ROWS ONLY ) AS 
PURGE_TABLE';

PREPARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT FROM V_CREATE_QUERY;
OPEN C1;  --NEW ADDED
WHILE(SQLCODE <>1000)
 DO
 EXECUTE V_DELETE_STATEMENT;
 COMMIT;  --NEW ADDED
END WHILE;
CLOSE C1  --NEW ADDED
end
```

Please let me know how to delete using COMMIT and WITH HOLD

Comment: @Mark Barinstein

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2: Purge large number of records from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426289/db2-purge-large-number-of-records-from-table)

Comment: @mao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426289/db2-purge-large-number-of-records-from-table is different as this is a stored Procedure

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear; you cannot open a cursor for a `delete` statement.

Comment: I get that for the error message,but let me know what are the other methods to correct this and make this delete happen

Comment: @mao the accepted answer is for bulk delete but  for a different scenario..please let me know if you can help with this

Comment: what is wrong with using `TRUNCATE table IMMEDIATE`?

Comment: Hi @PaulVernon,i wanted to delete based on a 'where' criteria,not truncate the full table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of errors.
You don't need any cursor for `delete`.
SQLCODE=`100` (and not `1000`) is returned, when no rows deleted. You must check it after the corresponding statement (`delete` in your case) immediately, and not after another statement (`commit` ?? in your example).

Should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
TABLE1.MYPROC1 ( IN A VARCHAR(100),IN B INTEGER,IN C INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLCODE int;
  DECLARE V_CREATE_QUERY VARCHAR(1024);
  DECLARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;

  SET V_CREATE_QUERY=
    'DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM '||a
  ||' WHERE KEY='||RTRIM(CHAR(B)
  ||' FETCH FIRST ' || RTRIM (CHAR(C)||' ROWS ONLY ) AS PURGE_TABLE';

  PREPARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT FROM V_CREATE_QUERY;
  DEL_LOOP: LOOP
    EXECUTE V_DELETE_STATEMENT;
    IF (SQLCODE = 100) THEN LEAVE DEL_LOOP; END IF;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP DEL_LOOP;
  COMMIT;
end
```

Comment: Hello Mark,thank you so much for the solution.I have made and small correction to the above SP. I have added an 'END IF;' after the 'COMMIT;'. This solution works for all the tables up till 400M rows,but it fails for a table with +500M rows with error 'Transaction logs getting full' .And i believe that this should not be the case as  we are already doing a COMMIT after every 10K . Any suggestions please?

Comment: @KKS I really forgot to close the `IF` statement, but it must be closed before the `COMMIT` statement, not after it. The code doesn’t commit properly otherwise. It must commit after every `DELETE`, but if you place `END IF;` after `COMMIT`, it commits only once after all deletes. Check the updated example.