# How to Truncate table in DB2? Error: Not a valid Command Line Processor command

Tags: sql, database, db2, truncate, db2-luw

Running following statement in DB2 CLP (Command Window)

> db2 "truncate table MYSCHEMA.TABLEA immediate"

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0969N  There is no message text corresponding to SQL error "-20356" in the
message file on this workstation.  The error was returned from module
"SQLNQBE2" with original tokens "MYSCHEMA.TABLEA".
```

Can some please tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing? I'm trying to simply truncate from a single table and I'm getting the following error message. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried it with/without quotes, with/without schema, with/without immediate. I've also tried in Command Editor (remove db2 and quotes) and still not working.  I'm using:
DB2/AIX64 9.7.9
Also, I have delete privilege as I am able to delete records but I want to truncate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006999/sql-query-to-truncate-table-in-ibm-db2

Comment: thnx but I actually started there. Tried what was suggested in that answer, followed link too but still no luck.  TRUNCATE TABLE someschema.sometable IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the DB2 client you're using doesn't seem to match that of the server, this is why you cannot see the actual error message for SQLCODE -20356. If you could, you'd see this:

> The table MYSCHEMA.TABLEA cannot be truncated because DELETE triggers
>   exist for the table, or the table is the parent in a referential
>   constraint.

Further explanation and suggested actions can be found, as usual, [in the fine manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql20356n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-20-246&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks. The table was a parent or had referential constraint. Went to the manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.TABLEA ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY WITH EMPTY TABLE
```

or

```
import from /dev/null of del replace into MYSCHEMA.TABLEA
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently too. In my case I had to do a COMMIT WORK right before TRUNCATE. This solved my problem. Please try and tell us if this helped.